# Point libfontconfig.so to a newer version of it

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, fontconfig

I am trying to convert a webpage with @font-face custom fonts to a pdf using wkhtmltopdf. The software gives me the following error when trying to do that conversion (when not using @font-face it works perfectly):

> wkhtmltopdf-i386: undefined symbol:
> FcFreeTypeQueryFace

I've found someone else with the same issue on the internet and apparently he fixed the problem doing this:

> Knowing that the problem was with
> libfontconfig, I went about updating
> it. I downloaded the source for
> version 2.4.2 (only needed the
> FcFreeTypeQueryFace call) from
> http://fontconfig.org/release/.
>
> I did
> a ./configure and make, and the file
> libfontconfig.so.1.2.0 was created in
> src/.libs/.
>
> I copied this file to /usr/lib/ and pointed the existing
> libfontconfig.so files to the new one.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=352&q=FCfreetypequeryface

So far I've been able to do the ./configure and get the proper file from src/.libs/. Now I'm stuck on trying to point the existing libfontconfig.so files to the new one, some help with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it ended up working renaming the old libfontconfig.so to libfontconfig.so.bak, then renaming the new file I'd built to libfontconfig.so. This might not be the best way to do it but it worked for me without linking or changing all kinds of configuration.